# Anyway to draw many lines fast in python? Matploblib is preferred if possible

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a geoJson file. A JSON type file and it has many points (387k) coordinates for 93k lines. I wonder if it's possible to use python plot all these lines into a figure fast, as I need to create many heat maps later for different time intervals.

Currently I'm using matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# draw road network
# roadSegs structure: {road_segment1:[[line1_x, line1_y],...],...}
figure, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(x_min - 100.0, x_max + 100.0)
ax.set_ylim(y_min - 100.0, y_max + 100.0)
for feature_id, lines in roadSegs.iteritems():
    for line in lines:
        ax.plot(line[0], line[1])
plt.savefig('road.png')
```

I need to use non-interactive backend as this code is going to be in the server. I try just drawing a single map. It has already taken 15mins and does not finish yet. Any idea to improve the speed? I know matplotlib is not designed for large dataset visualiation, but my dataset is less than 1M points. Any idea to improve its performance? If other libraries are recommended, which one should I use? At least it has to let me rendering lines and change the figure size.

Comment: Are the lines somehow connected? Is there any relationship between `[line1_x, line1_y]` and `[line2_x, line2_y]`?

Comment: does bokeh/datashader look helpful?  http://datashader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Yes. Some road_segment (the key) connects with a few others. So, I can get some longer lines and plot one instead of many. Is the bottomneck caused by "ax.plot" in the for loops? If I treat those lines as one long line, I got another problem: I need to render those lines under some road_segment to highlight them for heatmap creation.

Comment: If you can reduce the number of calls to `plt.plot` it will help most certainly. However I hightly doubt that plotting 93k lines makes any sense at all.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I know it's very expensive. But I'm drawing road network. Some single line roads are split into segments because of length, but most are split by intersections and turnings. I only have coordinates for points on each segments. It's difficult to reconstruct each road, as I don't know which segment belong to which road. Is there any library that allows me to draw each segment line cheaply?

Comment: @Max Power It looks like bokeh/datashader first aggregate data points and then visualize it. My problem is drawing a large road network on a figure, and I can also zoom in to see some highlighted segments.

Comment: Hi finix, I would guess that even if you defined a dummy 'aggregation' that just returns the raw lines, a single call to bokeh to plot that data would run much faster than 93k calls to ax.plt(). Although perhaps Bokeh violates your "non-interactive backend" specification.

Comment: @Max Power : Thank you. I'll give it a shot then. The Non-interactive is not as important as getting the image. If I cannot run it on the server, I'll just run it on my local machine.

Comment: nevermind your solution below is better. Nice going.

Comment: @Max Power Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a section under [pyplot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) that show to plot multiple lines, just do pyplot.plot(line1_x, line1_y, line2_x, line2_y,...). I simply change the code to call ax.plot() one time:

```
figure, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(x_min - 100.0, x_max + 100.0)
ax.set_ylim(y_min - 100.0, y_max + 100.0)
drawLines = []
for feature_id, lines in roadSegs.iteritems():
    for line in lines:
        drawLines.append(line[0])
        drawLines.append(line[1])
ax.plot(*drawLines)
plt.savefig('road.png')
```

It works now. Taking about 4 minutes to draw my road network. Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for pointing out my code's bottom-neck.

Comment: I guess you mean bottleneck :-D